# Controller can´t read parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I´m trying to add a select list to a form and having problems reading the submit params in the controller. This is in my "_form" view:

```
 <%=  select("project", "builder", Builder.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Choose builder'}) %>
```

This works nicely, all Builders in the database is showing up in the list. 
My controller´s "create" method looks like this:

```
@project = Project.new(project_params)
@project.builder = Builder.find(params[:builder])
```

Now, when choose a builder and submit my form I get the following error:

> Couldn't find Builder with 'id'=

The error page also prints out the parameters for the request, which looks correct:

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lhkFtWbWD12X7f8QHwaNo3nbkVyda6pKmlfidhGFqV+QXYyPL8GWvS8ICUMYKSQMXVYT/gornVDd3tmT6FvHVQ==",
     "project"=>{"name"=>"my project",
     "builder"=>"1"},
     "commit"=>"Create Project"}
```

The "Builder" object I chose here do have the Id 1. Any ideas on what´s causing this error=

Comment: Can you show the output of the query from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referencing `params[:builder]`, but the value is actually being passed as `params[:project][:builder]`. Try using that instead.